# How to remove part of an URL with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am trying to get Prestashop to work on my Linux server.

In the backend, the links return "Access denied", when they have "index.php".

i.e. this does not work:

shop/**mi**6**w*d5/index.php/sell/catalog/brands/?_token=Z******M7SQuhD2BRuKr********Amxq5S3mU

while this does

shop/**mi**6**w*d5/sell/catalog/brands/?_token=Z******M7SQuhD2BRuKr********Amxq5S3mU

How can I remove the "/index.php/" in the URL using .htaccess? Thank you.

Comment: Have you already removed `index.php` from your internal links?

Comment: I did not. Do you know, by any chance, where I can edit them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But that would seem to be what you need to do, rather than removing it with `.htaccess`. (You would only use `.htaccess` if you had already removed `index.php` from your internal links and this was an existing site and you needed to preserve SEO.)